# Canon vs Sigma 18-200 lens?

Tags: equipment-recommendation, canon, sigma

Which is better in terms of sharpness and chromatic aberration, the Sigma 18-200 DC OS HSM or the Canon EF-S 18-200 IS kit lens? I've read reviews on both lenses on dslrgear and other sites, but i need practical user experience.

Comment: I've found the best way to get real world comparisons is to go to flickr and search for pictures using those lenses. Most lenses will have an associated group where all the pictures submitted will be made using that particular lens: http://www.flickr.com/groups/18-200/ and http://www.flickr.com/groups/sigma_18-200mm/ - Though keep in mind these will be the best shots a lens is capable of, but we often judge lenses by their weaknesses, not strengths.

Comment: you are right, but these photos are often corrected in post-production. i was really hoping that someone who used both lenses to tell me the difference specially that renting is not an option right now.

Answer (score 2):

From [this comparison](http://www.the-digital-picture.com/Reviews/ISO-12233-Sample-Crops.aspx?Lens=491&Camera=474&Sample=0&FLI=0&API=0&LensComp=476&CameraComp=0&FLIComp=0&APIComp=0) I would say that the Canon is a better choice when considering CA and Sharpness. If you need practical advice - they both will do similarly and just fine for the uses for which they are designed. The Canon costs more, and for good reason. It does have higher grade optics.